# How to define navigation proptype in React navigation 5x

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am working new project. I started using typescript in this project. When I started the new project, I used react navigation 5x version. My question, how to define interface destructed navigation prop type in react navigation 5x version ? I don't use any type. I readed document react navigation, but i don't find my question. Thanks a lot. Have a nice days.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Text, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react';
import {Col, Grid} from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import Stores from '../../stores/storeIdentifier';
import ThemeStore from '../../stores/themeStore';

interface Props {
  navigation: any;
}
interface InjectedProps extends Props {
  themeStore: ThemeStore;
}

export function ModalComponent(props: Props) {
  const {themeStore, navigation} = props as InjectedProps;
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={themeStore.styleSheet.globalModal__container}>
      <Grid>
        <Col
          style={[
            themeStore.styleSheet.alignCenter,
            themeStore.styleSheet.justifyCenter,
          ]}>
          <Text>Welcome to Global Modal </Text>
          <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Back" />
        </Col>
      </Grid>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
export const Modal = inject(Stores.ThemeStore)(observer(ModalComponent));
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/typescript.html) guide?

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed this topic before I open it. but because I couldn't understand, I had to open this issue. The typescript topic of the new document is very complex. Is there a simple solution method?